# Is it possible to put a footer at the bottom of the last page using Chrome print?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know this has been asked multiple times before but none of those solutions have worked and hopefully since then someone has figured it out.

I have created a HTML page that i will be printing using Chromes browser print utility, i need to add an image at the bottom of the last page, the problem is that the content within the page is dynamic, so most methods i have looked at just place the image where the content ends, and not at the bottom of the last page.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style> 
        #footer:before {
            display: block;
            content: "";
            margin-top: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <img src="https://get.clt.re/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/footer-background-01.jpg" style="">
    </div> 
</body>
```

This is a very simplified example, the content will be dynamic so there could be multiple pages, and the image in the footer will be large,

essentially i need the footer to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh9s0.png

but only on the last printed page

any javascript or jquery solution is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You could essentialy generate two footers, one for your page content and one for printing. Use CSS then for displaying:

```
@media print {
   .content-footer {
      display: none;
   }
   .print-footer {
      display: block;
      //Always at the bottom
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this would solve the positioning issue

Comment: @O.M.N.L - that will place the footer at the bottom of the first printed page. See https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/6gsrvue2/58

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an answer here.  If you want to place that image on each page then Idan Cohen has a good solution here: https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a

As to just the last page ... not even the [CSS 2 Spec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html) for Paged Media supports a `:last` page selector (but does for `:first`).  But even `@page` is unreliable as most browsers have scaled down support for things like page counters etc. (See [@Page Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page#browser_compatibility))

Your best bet is to explore either a compromise *(either the image on each page, or the image at the end of the content - but not necessarily at the bottom of the page)* or explore the possibility of getting the job done via a JavaScript library that generates PDF on the fly.